# UIScrollView doesn't zoom layer

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, drawing, layer

Too much code to post here easily, so I thought I just try and check if I am in fact attempting the impossible first.

I have a scrollView which I can pan and zoom within, it works well. I am also drawing into a layer of a UIView that I add as a subview of the said scrollView.

Everything looked as if it was working, but I have just noticed a small snag.

I draw into the layer and I can pan around my image and drawing moves too. All good.

But when I zoom into my image, the image gets bigger... but the drawing remains the same size...  which isn't really what I wanted to happen. I wanted the drawing to zoom in too.

Is the normal behaviour?

Comment: Not sure if it's 100% relevant, but check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194808/swift-how-to-enable-pinch-to-zoom-for-calayer

Comment: That has almost fixed it! Thanks Nshuman. Added the layer to the image I was returning and not to the scrollView as I originally was!! Its good enough!!